# Debian Stuck at Booting from Hard Disk after installation on KVM

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, qemu, grub

I'm trying to install **Debian** on **Qemu-KVM** on RouterOS v5.25

I tried :

```
debian-10.8.0-i386-netinst.iso
debian-8.11.0-i386-kde-CD-1.iso
debian-live-9.0.0-i386-gnome.iso
```

on disk image created using : `qemu-img.exe create -f raw debian.img 10G`

during the installation process, everything is good to the end.

but right after finishing installation and rebooting, it shows the boot screen counting to 4 then it's stuck at

`Booting from Hard Disk...`

**GRUB** installed on (*master boot record*) during installation and i've tried to install it on (*/dev/sda*).

[image]

*Note :* it's not rebooting itself, it's just stuck.

Here's the boot parameters :

[image]

RouterOS **KVM** configuration :

[image]

*(for testing)* I installed `debian-6.0.10-i386-netinst.iso` it did install and boot without problems, but nothing higher than this version is booting.

What causes this problem?

Comment: Do you see anything after removing `quiet` from the `linux` line?

Comment: i see the same thing shown in the GIF above. nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to redirect the output of the kernel to your serial port. Remove the kernel option `console=ttyS0`.